# Math remainder quotient program for decimal values using Java/javascript

Tags: javascript, java, math

Hi I am trying to write a program using Javascript/Java to get the quotient (with decimal values) and remainder as shown in the below attachment. I used regular remainder operator (%) but not getting the actual remainder as shown below. Can someone please help me how to implement this.
[image]

Non-zero remainder:

[image]

In Javascript I wrote:

```
<script>
 var a = 17.0;
 var b = 5;
 var x = a % b;
</script>
```

Where as In Java when I wrote

```
import java.math.*;
public class CalculateRemainder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  float divider, remainder;
  int dividend;

  divider = 17.0f;
  dividend = 5;

  remainder = divider%(dividend);

  String str = "The remainder is " + remainder;
  System.out.println( str);
  }
 }
```

I am getting Remainder as "2.0" instead of "0" (as shown in the image). Same is the case with JavaScript.

Comment: In Java, that's because `remainder` is a `float`, and [that's how `float`s are printed](http://ideone.com/sT8PTw).

Comment: Actually I am looking for Javascript. But anything is fine between Java or Javascipt. If I get the proper solution is Java, I will implement it as "service" and will invoke it in Javascript. Ideally Javascript suites for my solution.

Comment: If you want it in Javascript, write your code in Javascript. Having a "service" to do this is just crazy.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. 17 divided by 5 is 3 with a remainder of 2. That's the standard definition of remainder. If you're supporting fractional quotients (e.g., 17/5=3.4), then there's no need for remainders since you can just carry out the fractional portion to an arbitrary number of decimal places...

Comment: Hi @DaoWen, yes thats true, but there are cases where we will get remainder as non-zero values right? So I am using them further in my program.

Comment: There is no **remainders** in float devision!

Comment: Hi @AndyTurner, I am actually looking for ideal solution. If I get solution in Javascript, then I am pretty much happy :)

Comment: "I am getting Remainder as "2.0" instead of "0"  why are you expecting 0 ?

Comment: Hi @c0der, if you see my another image where I am getting non-zero remainder (1). I need this value to be used in my another functionality.

Comment: You want the remainder after a certain precision???

Comment: if you don't want reminder only after a certain precision just multiply your number by 1000 (or other) before divide and multiple by the same number after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the remainder after some precision then use this:

```js
function remainder(dividend, divisor, precision = 4) {
  var result = (dividend / divisor).toString();
  var dot = result.indexOf('.');
  if(dot == -1) return 0; // it was a perfect division (9 / 3 for example)
  
  var remainder = "0." + result.substr(dot + precision);  // get the part after the precision
  return Math.round(remainder * divisor);                 // multiply it by the divisor and round the result
}

console.log(remainder(9.1, 3, 3));
```

**Note:** The result could be different for different precisions.

Comment: Wowww @ibrahim, Its amazing. You saved my day. Thank you so much for the quick solution. :)

Comment: This is way more complex than necessary. You should use the solution suggested by bormat in the comments above (i.e., if you want the remainder after 3 decimal places, just multiply your dividend by 1000, do the math using normal integer arithmetic, and then divide the results by 1000.0 to get the expected floating-point value).